# Error name values is not defined in MYSQL With Python in the system register

Tags: python, mysql

In the my loop "while true" in option "if" below, i received the error "name 'declaracao' is not defined".
And as a test to see if the INSERT command is working, I'm just printing to the screen.

Some light from friends. Eu sou novato na programação sql.
Regards,

But the result is:

> name 'declaracao' is not defined
> INSERT INTO cadteste(nrpedido, nome, endereco, numero) VALUES ('{nrkpedido}', '{knome}', '{kendereco}',}', '{knumero}')

Code:

```
if window == cadastro1 and event == 'Cadastrar' and values['knome'] == ''\
    and values['kpedido'] == '' and values['kendereco'] == '' and values['kcep'] == '' and values['kbairro'] == ''\
    and values['kestado'] == '' and values['kcomplemento'] == '' and values['ktelefone'] == ''\
    and values['kcidade'] == '':
    sg.popup('Preencha todos os campos')
    continue
elif event == 'Cadastrar':
    p = 'kpedido'
    n = 'knome'
    e = 'kendereco'
    nu = 'knumero'
 
    my_data = (p, n, e, nu)
    dados = p + ',' + n + ',' + nu + ','')'
    declaracao1 = ("INSERT INTO cadteste(nrpedido, nome, endereco, numero) VALUES ('{nrkpedido}', '{knome}', '{kendereco}',}', '{knumero}')")
    sql = declaracao1
    print(declaracao1)
```

Comment: I don't see `declaracao` anywhere in the code you posted. It has `declaracao1`.

Comment: Please post the full traceback. Which line is getting that error?

Comment: Is `declaracao1` supposed to be an f-string?

Comment: Excuse-me, the "declaracao' is in other part code, that has the same code mysql. I solved refer this variable 'declaracao'. Now, in this loop if below for the query and print in the screen print(declaracao1) in this point, received only the code, and don´t receive the query database. Why?

Comment: See part code, because has limit characters for send.

        elif event == 'Cadastrar':
                my_data = (p, n, e, nu, co, ba, ci, es, ce, te, ob)
                dados = p + ',' + n + ',' + nu + ',' + co + ',' ')'
                declaracao1 = ("INSERT INTO cadteste(nrpedido, nome, endereco, numero) VALUES ('{nrkpedido}', '{knome}', '{kendereco}',}', '{knumero}')")
                sql = declaracao1
                print(declaracao1)

Comment: You're never executing the query, you're just printing it. If you want placeholders in the query, you should use `%s`, not things like `'{nkrpedido}'`

Comment: See the examples of using placeholders and parameters here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html

Comment: Thank´s a lot my friends. In this moment of the student don´t is easy. kkk See the link with the fullcode.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DVbTJNlt6rhu8W86-kvuVjDyajTty3Wl/view?usp=sharing